# Выравнивание по центру вывод в с++

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь в форматном выводе. Нужно устанавливать фиксированую ширину поля. 
И выравнивать по центру слово. Пересмотрел форматный вывод ничего не нашел. Нужен пример кода.

Comment: 1. какого поля? 2. какой интерфейс имеет программа(консольный/графический)? 3.Середина относительно чего???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например с помощью манипуляторов

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    cout <<'|' << setw(10)  << "word1" << setw(5) << '|' 
         << setw(10)  << "word2" << setw(5) << '|' << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

слова `"word1"` и `"word2"` будут находится в середине между символами `'|'`

Answer (score 2):

При условии, что все слова будут либо четные, либо нечетные.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void PrintWord(const string& s){
    int width_field = 12; //ширина поля
    string v(width_field, '.'); //для наглядности заполняем точками
    string v1;

    int l_word = s.size();
    int l_field = v.size();
    int step = (l_field - l_word)/2;

    for(int i = 0; i < l_word; i++){
        v1.push_back(s[i]);
    }
    copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(),v.begin()+step);
    for(auto x : v){
        cout << x;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
//Пример вывода
    PrintWord("ad"); //2
    PrintWord("admi"); //4
    PrintWord("admira"); //6
    PrintWord("admirati"); //8
    PrintWord("admiration"); //10

    PrintWord("a"); //1
    PrintWord("adm"); //3
    PrintWord("admir"); //5
    PrintWord("admirat"); //7
    PrintWord("admiratio"); //9

    return 0;
}
```